# Ловлю exсeption при Get соединение(Retrofit 2.1)

Tags: java, android

Сам Get:

```
public interface GetDescriptionForecastApi {
@GET("feed_android.php")
Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> getList (@Query("action=get_description&id=") int id);}
```

А вот в адаптере к RecylcerView вызываю это запрос при нажатию на CardView:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ForecastViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DataForecast.DataBean searchModel = list.get(position);
    holder.timedate.setText(searchModel.getDate());
    holder.game.setText(searchModel.getCommand());
    holder.forecast.setText("Фора1 по очкам (-4.5) @ " + searchModel.getKf());

    holder.cv_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.about.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                GetDescriptionForecastApi service =
                        GetDescriptionForecastService.getInstance(holder.cv_forecast.getContext()).getApi();
                Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> descriptionCall =
                        service.getList(searchModel.getId());

                descriptionCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetDescriptionForecastModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> call, Response<GetDescriptionForecastModel> response) {
                        GetDescriptionForecastModel dataDescription = response.body();
                        result  = dataDescription.getData();
                        holder.about.setText(result);
                        holder.about.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.cv_forecast.setBackgroundResource(R.color.forecast_about_all);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Tag", t.getMessage()); // здесь всегда оказываюсь
                    }
                });

            } else {
                holder.about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.cv_forecast.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

ну и тут сам сервис который строит retrofit:

```
public class GetDescriptionForecastService {
private static GetDescriptionForecastService instance;

public static GetDescriptionForecastService getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GetDescriptionForecastService(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://******.ru/***/";
private GetDescriptionForecastApi api;

private GetDescriptionForecastService(Context context) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    }).build();

    Retrofit retrofitRef = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    api = retrofitRef.create(GetDescriptionForecastApi.class);
}


public GetDescriptionForecastApi getApi() {
    return api;    }}
```

Получается такой Exсeption в адаптере CardView:

> E/Tag: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: почему exeption

Comment: Похоже на то, что JSON не валидный, залогируйте ответ, посмотрите что присылает сервер.

Comment: намекните как мне залогировать, а то я не понимаю где именно

Comment: Добавить interceptor `HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);` вашему okHttpClient! Ну и добавить зависимость `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'` и смотреть лог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас как-то странно интерфейс с параметрами выглядит. Надо параметры разделять. Как-то так:

```
public interface GetDescriptionForecastApi {
@GET("feed_android.php")
Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> getList (@Query("action") String action, @Query("id") int id);}
```

Вызывать так:

```
Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> descriptionCall =
                    service.getList("get_description", searchModel.getId());
```

Comment: Вы как всегда на высоте!! Спасибо огромное! У Вас нету предположений почему также срабатывает на каждый 14 элемент RecyclerView?  И почему с notifyDataSetChanged() не обновляет?

Comment: На счёт срабатывания не знаю, а notifyDataSetChanged не срабатывает, видимо, потому, что вы назначаете новые данные для элементов разметки, а не обновляете данные в списке данных адаптера. Если результат запроса поместить в список моделей и вызвать обновление, то должно сработать