# Как правильно логировать полученый JSON и чем?

Tags: java, android

Вот сам класс где я получаю JSON:

```kotlin
public class GetDescriptionForecastService {
    private static GetDescriptionForecastService instance;

    public static GetDescriptionForecastService getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GetDescriptionForecastService(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://******.ru/***/";
    private GetDescriptionForecastApi api;

    private GetDescriptionForecastService(Context context) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }).build();

        Retrofit retrofitRef = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        api = retrofitRef.create(GetDescriptionForecastApi.class);
    }

    public GetDescriptionForecastApi getApi() {
        return api;
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее что вы хотите увидеть в ответе. Возможно вам просто надо toString() на полученном объекте вызвать?

Comment: этот вопрос всплывает от этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573486/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8E-exeption-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-get-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5retrofit-2-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно поменять тип ответа на `Response<ResponceBody>` и тогда выводить ответ так

```
descriptionCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponceBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponceBody> call, Response<ResponceBody> response) {
        String body = response.body();
        Log.d(TAG, "body: " + body);
        GetDescriptionForecastModel dataDescription = ...;// тут вручную приведите чем-то типа Gson переменную body в ваш класс
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<GetDescriptionForecastModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Tag", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Так вы в логах увидите непосредственно сырой ответ сервера