# Ошибка при получении JSON файла

Tags: android, json, kotlin, rest

Пытаюсь получить JSON файл от сервера и заполнить список этими данными. Проблема в том, что я получаю следующую ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $` Я понимаю что в Service можно заменить `Call<ProductList>` на `Call<List<ProductList>>`и ошибка исчезнет. Но я не хочу работать с массивом. Идея в том что мой JSON файл содержит категории(массивы с данными) я создал для них необходимые POJO классы, а сейчас хочу "объединить" категории из JSON с моими классами POJO. Посоветуйте как это сделать избегая использования `Call<List<ProductList>>`.
JSON файл:

```
{
  "beauty_health": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "brand": "Kaya Youth",
      "category": "Beauty & Health",
      "name": "Hydro Replenish Face Wash",
      "description": "Hydro Replenish Face Wash, With Aloe Vera",
      "price": 42,
      "icon": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "brand": "Kaya Youth",
      "category": "Beauty & Health",
      "name": "Oxy-Infusion Face Wash",
      "description": "Kaya Youth Oxy-Infusion Face Wash,100",
      "price": 18,
      "icon": ""
    }],
  "electronics": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "brand": "OnePlus",
      "category": "Electronics",
      "name": "OnePlus 8",
      "description": "OnePlus 8T 64GB",
      "price": 250,
      "icon": ""
    },],
```

Главный Pojo класс:

```
class ProductList {
    @SerializedName("beauty_health")
    var beautyHealth: List<BeautyHealth>? = null

    @SerializedName("electronics")
    var electronics: List<Electronic>? = null

    @SerializedName("fashion")
    var fashion: List<Fashion>? = null

    @SerializedName("sports")
    var sports: List<Sport>? = null

    @SerializedName("popular")
    var popular: List<Popular>? = null

    @SerializedName("image_slider")
    var imageSlider: List<ImageSlider>? = null
}
```

Пример POJO класса категории:

```
class BeautyHealth {
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("brand")
    var brand: String? = null

    @SerializedName("category")
    var category: String? = null

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("description")
    var description: String? = null

    @SerializedName("price")
    var price: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("icon")
    var icon: String? = null
}
```

Service:

```
@GET(value = "Store-Products")
    fun onFetchAllProducts() : Call<ProductList>
```

Запрос:

```
val api = retrofit.create(StoreAPI::class.java)
        api.onFetchAllProducts().enqueue(object : Callback<ProductList> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductList>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductList>, response: Response<ProductList>) {
                mutableLiveData.postValue(response.body())
            }
        })
        return mutableLiveData
```

Comment: Если вы не хотите использовать List<ProductList>, то вам нужно исправить формат данных, который возвращает сервер.

Comment: Приходит с сервера список, значить надо парсить список. Потом этот список трансформируйте во что угодно.

Comment: А как на самом деле выглядит json? Кусок, который вы показали, вполне соответствует классу `ProductList`. Если у вас приходит массив из таких кусков, то варианта два: 1) получать таки `List<ProductList>` и потом мержить в цикле в один объект; 2) писать кастомный адаптер для `Gson` и, по большому счёту, делать в нём тоже самое, но это будет ещё более не удобно чем первый, плюс только в том, что логика будет вынесена в адаптер

Comment: @woesss JSON выглядит так как в вопросе, только категорий больше. Проблема в том что мне нужно создать RecyclerView в котором будут категории и товары. И не очень хочется перебирать этот JSON и создавать массивы с отдельными категориями

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю: ваш POJO 100% подходит для json, представленного в вопросе. Возможно что-то не так с самим запросом и вы получаете другой ответ, а не тот что ожидается. Проверьте содержимое ответа под отладчиком или с помощью логирования так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827 или так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573800/11515